# SQL Selected Data and VBScript

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

Edited Question:

I have three tables that i am using joins on to pull out one recordset of data that is in the following format.

```
tbl_hours: jobID, bosstaskID, date, starttime, endtime, hours
tbl_jobs: jobID : other fields
tbl_tasks: taskID, officetaskID :other fields
```

SELECT output of all records

```
empID   hHours  hStartTime              hStopTime               taskID      officeTaskID    hDate                   jobID
1      .50      2018-06-25 07:00:00.000 2018-06-25 07:30:00.000 LOAD        Load Up/UNL     2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1      .25      2018-06-25 07:30:00.000 2018-06-25 07:45:00.000 DT          Drive Time      2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1      1.25     2018-06-25 07:45:00.000 2018-06-25 09:00:00.000 PATH        Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1      .25      2018-06-25 09:00:00.000 2018-06-25 09:15:00.000 BREAK       Break           2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1      .75      2018-06-25 09:15:00.000 2018-06-25 10:00:00.000 OUT-TERM    Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1      .75      2018-06-25 10:00:00.000 2018-06-25 10:45:00.000 HEAD-TERM   Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1      .50      2018-06-25 10:45:00.000 2018-06-25 11:15:00.000 TEST        Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1      1.00     2018-06-25 11:15:00.000 2018-06-25 12:15:00.000 LUNCH       Lunch           2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1      1.00     2018-06-25 12:15:00.000 2018-06-25 13:15:00.000 ROUGH       Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 2
1      .75      2018-06-25 13:15:00.000 2018-06-25 14:00:00.000 OUT-TERM    Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 2
1      .75      2018-06-25 14:00:00.000 2018-06-25 14:45:00.000 HEAD-TERM   Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 2
1      .50      2018-06-25 14:45:00.000 2018-06-25 15:15:00.000 TEST        Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 2
1      .25      2018-06-25 15:15:00.000 2018-06-25 15:30:00.000 BREAK       Break           2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 2
1      .50      2018-06-25 15:30:00.000 2018-06-25 16:00:00.000 ST          Shop Time       2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 NULL
1      1.00     2018-06-25 16:00:00.000 2018-06-25 17:00:00.000 ROUGH       Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
1      1.00     2018-06-25 17:00:00.000 2018-06-25 18:00:00.000 FIBER-TERM  Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
1      .50      2018-06-25 18:00:00.000 2018-06-25 18:30:00.000 TEST        Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
1      .50      2018-06-25 18:30:00.000 2018-06-25 19:00:00.000 LOAD        Load Up/UNL     2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
1      .25      2018-06-25 19:00:00.000 2018-06-25 19:15:00.000 BREAK       Break           2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
1      .50      2018-06-25 19:15:00.000 2018-06-25 19:45:00.000 JS          Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
```

When I use the following SQL query I can get it close to the format I want except where you see the final break period.  It selects the max(hStopTime) of a task after the break.

SQL Query

```
        SELECT tbl_employees.empID, SUM(tbl_hours.hHours) as hHours,
        Min(tbl_hours.hStartTime) as hStartTime, 
        Max(tbl_hours.hStopTime) as hStopTime,
        tbl_task.taskPrintShort as officeTaskID, tbl_hours.hDate, 
        tbl_jobs.jobID 
        FROM ((tbl_Hours LEFT JOIN tbl_task ON tbl_hours.codeID = tbl_task.taskID) 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_employees on tbl_hours.empID=tbl_employees.empID) 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_jobs on tbl_hours.jobID = tbl_jobs.jobID
        WHERE tbl_hours.empID=1 and tbl_hours.hDate='2018-06-25'
        GROUP BY tbl_employees.empID, tbl_jobs.jobID, tbl_task.taskPrintShort, 
        tbl_employees.empFirst, tbl_employees.empLast, tbl_hours.hDate
        ORDER BY tbl_hours.hStartTime
```

The output from the above SELECT statement.

```
empID     hHours  hStartTime              hStopTime         OfficeTaskID    hDate                   jobID
1   .50   2018-06-25 07:00:00.000   2018-06-25 07:30:00.000 Load Up/UNL     2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1   .25   2018-06-25 07:30:00.000   2018-06-25 07:45:00.000 Drive Time      2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1   3.25  2018-06-25 07:45:00.000   2018-06-25 11:15:00.000 Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1   .25   2018-06-25 09:00:00.000   2018-06-25 09:15:00.000 Break           2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1   1.00  2018-06-25 11:15:00.000   2018-06-25 12:15:00.000 Lunch           2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 1
1   3.00  2018-06-25 12:15:00.000   2018-06-25 15:15:00.000 Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 2
1   .25   2018-06-25 15:15:00.000   2018-06-25 15:30:00.000 Break           2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 2
1   .50   2018-06-25 15:30:00.000   2018-06-25 16:00:00.000 Shop Time       2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 NULL
1   3.00  2018-06-25 16:00:00.000   2018-06-25 19:45:00.000 Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
1   .50   2018-06-25 18:30:00.000   2018-06-25 19:00:00.000 Load Up/UNL     2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
1   .25   2018-06-25 19:00:00.000   2018-06-25 19:15:00.000 Break           2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
```

This is the problem line.

```
1   3.00  2018-06-25 16:00:00.000   2018-06-25 19:45:00.000 Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
```

I need the last lines to group up like this example

```
1   2.50  2018-06-25 16:00:00.000   2018-06-25 18:30:00.000 Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
1   .50   2018-06-25 18:30:00.000   2018-06-25 19:00:00.000 Load Up/UNL     2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
1   .25   2018-06-25 19:00:00.000   2018-06-25 19:15:00.000 Break           2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
1   .50   2018-06-25 19:15:00.000   2018-06-25 19:45:00.000 Job Site        2018-06-25 00:00:00.000 3
```

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is get a start time and stop time for all officeTaskID's that are of the type 'Job Site'. The same task may be performed before or after another task (such as a break). My office manager doesn't want to see all of the task information that I find useful.

Can my conundrum be solved?

Edit: Requested Version Information -

> Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2066 (Intel X86)   May 11 2012 18:41:14   Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Comment: Yes. Is this SQL Server? Can you post your existing SQL query?

Comment: added it into my main post because it was longer than I had room in this box. thanks.

Comment: Thanks - that's what you're meant to do. So is this on SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. It is on SQL Server. Version is 2003.

Comment: There's no SQL 2003 but I'll just edit the tag to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an aggregate and a group by.

```
SELECT 
tbl_employees.empID, tbl_jobs.jobShort as jobID, 
tbl_task.taskShort as taskID, tbl_task.taskPrintShort as OfficeID, 
tbl_hours.hDate as date, 
MIN(tbl_hours.hStartTime) as StartTime, 
MAX(tbl_hours.hStopTime) As StopTime, 
SUM(tbl_hours.hHours) as Hours
FROM ((tbl_Hours LEFT JOIN tbl_task ON tbl_hours.codeID = tbl_task.taskID) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_employees on tbl_hours.empID=tbl_employees.empID) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_jobs on tbl_hours.jobID = tbl_jobs.jobID
WHERE tbl_hours.empID=1 and tbl_hours.hDate='2018-06-25'
GROUP BY 
tbl_employees.empID, tbl_jobs.jobShort, 
tbl_task.taskShort, tbl_task.taskPrintShort, tbl_hours.hDate
ORDER BY tbl_hours.hStartTime
```

Note I have changed the date to a more reliable format (ISO)

Comment: Thank you. However I've tried this on my own. What I run into is if an employee works on the same task before and after a break period (breaks are also a task).. The startTime pulls correctly, but it pulls the max(stopTime) after the break period. (Example : Start Time 9:00 - End Time 12:00 hours 2, the break from Start 11:15 End Time: 11:30 hours 0.25). With a third line with a different third completed task.

Comment: That case was not in your sample data. I suggest you edit your question and add it. From your explanation, the easiest thing to do might be to exclude it with a where clause

Comment: Thanks much for your help sir,  but I'm just going to pass. I'm just going to make the office manager deal with all of the data collection I want. Ultimately I believe it will lead to less issues in the long run anyway, because I don't believe a SELECT statement can be written to catch every possible scenario that 'could' happen.

Comment: I'm sure it could. You have a choice of putting business rules in efficient, server based, reusable SQL, or inefficient, client side VBScript. If you are serious about doing this kind of reporting you need to define a view or stored procedure in the database that works it out for you. If you start putting complex business rules in VBScript it's very difficult to reuse and scale.... but its true some stuff just isn't so important that it needs to be re-engineered.

Comment: Nick- Since you feel this can be solved, I've completely changed the original post to reflect what I'm asking.  I've included actual data that I'm looking at from my database. I hope I've made it clear enough for you. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: OK so this is either a 'pick the correct grouping key' problem, which is just a matter of fiddling with the `group by`, or it is an 'islands and gaps' problem which is solvable but much more complicated. I think it's an islands and gaps problem - the only reason we want to break out the last "Job Site" record is because there are different record types "prior" to it on the same day

Comment: Not really sure what you said there as I really am an SQL novice. It is knowledge I gained 20+ years ago working in call centers and creating custom crystal reports. That being said, I guess what I need for it to do is when it hits the last officeTaskID is to stop and not go past that point in grouping.  It does that in the other two groupings which you can see in the second set of output. and yes to your final statement.  Ultimately this is a timesheet and the start and stop times matter. and they should be in order.

Comment: "I guess what I need for it to do is when it hits the last officeTaskID is to stop and not go past that point in grouping" 

Change the above to

I guess what I need for it to do is when it hits the last officeTaskID in a group for it to stop and not go past that point in grouping

Comment: Sorry for all the lingo! Can you run `SELECT @@VERSION` in your database then edit the question and post your results. There is a solution for this but the complexity depends on what your SQL Server version is.... and I'm not 100% that I'll get back and answer this for you but anyway please add the SQL Server version.

Comment: Done.. It is much older version than I thought..  If you can't figure out a way I'm ok with that. I'll just tell her it isn't possible at this time. We're a small company which is why I'm writing this app vs buying something or having it written.  Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: TBH if you bought an app it probably wouldn't run against SQL 2000 - that is very old unsupported version. It is possible to do but probably not practical to do on your version of SQL Server